# How can I make this background image cover the FULL HTML background?

Tags: css

I am very aware of ´background-size:cover;´ etc, but this case is different. **There is something that defines the height of the HTML / BODY in this page - and I can not fathom what it is.**

I have tried everything I know and remember for the past 2 hours, but somehow the background will not cover. It seems to be due to the body adjusting the height to some formula instead of the real size of the screen.

I see it best when my screen is about 1300px wide.

Can you see what causes the problem?

Now I just enter some few lines of code.

The image was NOT covering the full screen. The solution was to add the answer below in the CSS:

`body, html {height:100%}`

That fixed it all.

[image]

Comment: Fine for me in chrome

Comment: Not only does posting the relevant code here help future visitors, it helps you. By troubleshooting your own issue in coming up with a minimal code example that reproduces the issue, many times users discover their own error in the process and avoid having to post a question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

add `height: 100vh;` to this rule :

```
body>.multibg {

    height: 100vh;
}
```

this will solve the issue i'm pretty sure !!

> Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax - CR Length units representing 1%
>   of the viewport size for viewport width (vw), height (vh), the smaller
>   of the two (vmin), or the larger of the two (vmax).

browsers compatibility for **[Viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)**

Comment: That did also work. What is 100vh ?

Comment: yes try and you will see :)

Comment: you don't have to set the body at 100%

Comment: I saw that it worked. I just don't know what the unit ´vh´ is :-)

Comment: vh it's the Viewport height

Comment: +1 for viewport units and support..but some compatibility issues with IE9, IOS7 and opera..workaround for iOS7  can be found at https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587..

Answer (score 1):

Please add height: 100% on body and html

Comment: When I did it just became a VERY long website. (I use Chrome)

Comment: No, you are right. I mixed up another class when doing so (auto fill in the browser)

Comment: Amazing I didn't see this. That is almost embarassing ;-)  Will set this to the answer, but am not allowed yet by SO.

Comment: haha... sometime happen 
http://prntscr.com/6clf7l